# How can I copy the entire command of a process in `glances`?

Tags: command, monitoring, glances

The command of each process in `glances` is chopped by default, e.g. `/opt/conda/bin/python`:

```
trainman-k8s-job-afe4dad6-d612-4564-979a-89a82594674e-rnnpf                                Uptime: 31 days, 20:33:38

CPU      10.4%  nice:     0.0%        LOAD    64-core        MEM      5.6%  active:    24.5G        SWAP      0.0%
user:     4.2%  irq:      0.3%        1 min:    8.67         total:   480G  inactive:  20.9G        total:       0
system:   5.7%  iowait:   0.0%        5 min:    8.34         used:   26.9G  buffers:    442M        used:        0
idle:    89.6%  steal:    0.0%        15 min:   8.12         free:    453G  cached:    24.1G        free:        0

NETWORK     Rx/s   Tx/s   TASKS 44 (184 thr), 5 run, 38 slp, 1 oth sorted automatically by cpu_percent, flat view
eth0         1Kb   24Kb
lo          520b   520b     CPU%  MEM%  VIRT   RES   PID USER        NI S    TIME+ IOR/s IOW/s Command
                            98.7   1.0 47.0G 4.80G 18795 root         0 R 21:13.45     0     0 /opt/conda/bin/python
DISK I/O     R/s    W/s     98.4   1.0 47.1G 4.80G 18797 root         0 R 19:51.70     0     0 /opt/conda/bin/python
dm-0           0      0     98.4   0.9 46.4G 4.20G 18792 root         0 R 50:25.84     0     0 /opt/conda/bin/python
xvda1          0      0     98.1   1.0 47.1G 4.80G 18796 root         0 R 48:36.66     0     0 /opt/conda/bin/python
xvda2          0      0     98.1   1.0 46.8G 4.81G 18794 root         0 R 21:50.84     0     0 /opt/conda/bin/python
xvda3          0      0      1.6   0.0 1.02G  111M 18932 root         0 S 13:46.50     0     0 /opt/conda/bin/python
xvda4          0      0      1.3   0.0 1.02G  107M 18944 root         0 S 12:12.99     0     0 /opt/conda/bin/python
xvda6          0      0      1.3   0.0 1.02G  113M 18924 root         0 S 12:47.56     0     0 /opt/conda/bin/python
xvda7          0      0      1.3   0.0 1.02G  110M 18942 root         0 S  4:06.40     0     0 /opt/conda/bin/python
xvda9          0   146K      1.3   0.0 1.02G  109M 18935 root         0 S  2:14.80     0     0 /opt/conda/bin/python
xvdbl          0      0      1.0   0.0 92.6M 30.6M3024398 root         0 R  0:04.85     0     0 /usr/bin/python3 /us
                             0.3   0.0 13.0M 3.03M698340 root         0 S 35:14.51     0     0 watch -n 0.1 nvidia-s
FILE SYS    Used  Total      0.3   0.0  410M 65.3M    70 root         0 S 46:53.78     0     0 /opt/conda/bin/python
_tion-log   268G   482G
_tc/hosts   268G   482G
2022-02-23 04:25:54       No warning or critical alert detected
```

Comment: Do you mean the command line by "entire command"? You can easily access the full command line with other commands, e.g. `ps`, forcing non-terminal mode with something like `| cat` if necessary.

Comment: @dirkt thanks, yes entire command

Answer (score 3):

Read its documentation ([Glances](https://glances.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aoa/ps.html)) and found this :

Pressing `/` will shorten the command path i.e. where the command executable is stored. This would give you some extra information. Although if your command is too long then better to switch to ps and its options like `ps aux`

I think this also has to do with the column size of the terminal you are using.
My current column size is 210 and I can see the whole command after pressing `/`

Before pressing `/`:

[image]

After pressing `/`

[image]

Check the column size of you terminal as well.

My current Column size is 210 an I'm using a 27 inch monitor.